# How to extract ROI of a 3D Model with Python

Tags: python, 3d, image-segmentation

I want to extract a specific ROI out of a 3D Model that i created but i have no idea how to do this. I also performed a binary segmentation on one of the images i used for the mesh generation. Now i want to cut out my segmented region out of the mesh.

After a few days of research i still got no clue how to perform this exactly. I have following worklfow in my head:

- generate mesh with photogrammetry approach
- create binary mask for specific image (most middle one)
- convert mesh to 3d array (if possible?)
- do array operation and combine 2d array (binary mask) with 3d array and set all values in 3d array to 0 that are not in my ROI
- create mesh out of new 3D array

I'm still not sure if this could work. Is there any standard python approach to this?
I appreciate your time.